# VBA Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when using Range method

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyNPaste()

Dim Columncount_s1 As Long
Dim Columncount As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, K As Long
Dim Sheetcount As Long
Dim LastRow_s1 As Long, LastRow As Long


Columncount_s1 = Sheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Sheetcount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For i = 2 To Sheetcount
    Columncount = Sheets(i).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For j = 1 To Columncount_s1
        For K = 1 To Columncount
            If Sheets(1).Cells(1, j) = Sheets(i).Cells(1, K) Then
                LastRow_s1 = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, j).End(3)(2).Row
                LastRow = Sheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, K).End(3)(2).Row
                Sheets(i).Range(Cells(2, K), Cells(LastRow, K)).Copy
                Sheets(1).Cells(LastRow, j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        Next K
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

I tried to make a code to copy and paste to the right column in vba. But the Sheets(i).Range(Cells(2,K... this line keep causing error. Is that because I used too many of variables to the parameter of method Range?

The purpose of the code was to consolidate the data by copying and pasting columns that have the same header from a different sheet.

Comment: In this code - `Sheets(i).Range(Cells(2, K), Cells(LastRow, K)).Copy` the parts that say `Cells(2, K)` refer to whatever sheet is active at the time. Is that your intent? You may want to qualify them with the same sheet reference you are using for the main `Range`

Comment: Oh no I thought if I write like that then it would be sheet(i)'s cells(2,k)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and use the debug window to double check the values.

Comment: Also keep in mind that depending on context, `Cells(2, K)` can be a value, and it can be a cell object reference. If you want the value, use `Cells(2, K).Value` explicitly.

Comment: Maybe try `range(sheets(i).cells(2,K),sheets(i).cells(lastrow,K)).copy` ?

Comment: Thank you guys! I figured out the problem, thanks a lot!! I think I didn't know about the cells method well, so I put the Worksheets().Activate code and it worked very well!